# show reports using graphs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, crystal-reports, graph

I am currently using MS Charts to display information from my reports.

Is there a way I can display the reports in a better way, for example using Silverlight or something which is free for commercial use?

I want the reports graphs to just stand out.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL Server Reporting Service. Take a look at this [ASP.Net charting demo](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/net-4/chart/aspnet-4-how-do-i-introducing-the-new-chart-control-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: hey thanks for the link... but as you can see the reports dont look appealing.. as in they are not fancy enough... ms charts also offer someting similar to this...isn't there anything free like telerik i want my reports to look graphical... thanks though...

Comment: You are right.It doesn't give that much detail.Anyways it might help you as an option that chart reporting can be done using SQL Server Reporting service.